# free RTOS porting on STM32F407VGT6

Tags: freertos, stm32f4discovery

I want to port freeRTOS on STM32F407VGT6 MCU.I searched the web but didnt found any suitable link to do this.
Please suggest a suitable method to achieve this or any web link describing the
steps.

Thanks
Amit

Edit : - I want to port freeRTOS on STM32F4 discovery board

Answer (score 5):

First, the STM32Cube software from ST themselves will generate a FreeRTOS project that targets that board for you.

Also, a basic Google search shows this https://github.com/wangyeee/STM32F4-FreeRTOS

...and then there is this: https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-for-STM32F4xx-Cortex-M4F-IAR.html along with these pages:  https://www.freertos.org/porting-a-freertos-demo-to-different-hardware.html https://www.freertos.org/Creating-a-new-FreeRTOS-project.html